# How to add Zoom + Drag Behaviour to an external SVG loaded into D3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, d3.js, svg

What I want to do, is load an existing SVG (in XML format) into D3.

It works fine, until the point where I start to add Zoom + Drag Behaviour to the SVG.

Actually adding the behaviour seems to work, but when I drag the objects in the SVG, there are strange jumps (or flickering). It gets even worse after one zooms, then the object moves far more, than it should.

I think you will understand what I mean, immediately after trying the code example.

How can I make Zoom + Drag behave, as they should?

Thanks in advance

```js
var main_chart_svg = document.body;

d3.xml("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg", function(error, documentFragment) {
        if (error) {console.log(error); return;}
    
        var svgNode = documentFragment
                    .getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
    
        main_chart_svg.appendChild(svgNode);
        
        d3.selectAll('circle').style('fill', 'green'); //only in order to show, that selections work

        //this is where my problem happens
        d3.select('svg').call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
          d3.select('svg').attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
        }));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are performing your zoom/pan transformation on the `svg` element.  It's usually applied on a `g` element that wraps what you are zooming. To use a `g`, in your case, you'll need to insert this element into your already existing `svg`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var main_chart_svg = document.body;

    d3.xml("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg", function(error, documentFragment) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }

      var svgNode = documentFragment
        .getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];

      main_chart_svg.appendChild(svgNode);

      var svg = d3.select('svg'),
        g = svg.append('g');

      g.node().appendChild(svg.select('circle').node());

      d3.selectAll('circle').style('fill', 'green'); //only in order to show, that selections work

      //this is where my problem happens
      d3.select('svg').call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
        g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
      }));
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to do that, you could apply the zoom directly to the circle:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var main_chart_svg = document.body;

    d3.xml("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg", function(error, documentFragment) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }

      var svgNode = documentFragment
        .getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];

      main_chart_svg.appendChild(svgNode);

      var svg = d3.select('svg'),
        c = d3.select('circle');


      c.style('fill', 'green'); //only in order to show, that selections work

      //this is where my problem happens
      d3.select('svg').call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
        c.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
      }));
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```